# commas in "They are sweet, not sour, grapes"

Tags: punctuation, commas

In the sentence "They are sweet, not sour, grapes.", is the second comma correct, incorrect, or optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it is correct, and while it is arguably optional, I think in this case it is better left in, especially because there is an English idiom, 'sour grapes', which roughly means someone speaking or acting negatively due to jealousy.

Comment: +1 thank you. My question was general and I just happened to choose the reference to "sour" and "grapes". I guess it is optional in general but it is better safe than sorry to leave it in?

Comment: It is a style choice. A rule of thumb is to read it out loud. Where you naturally feel the need to pause, put a comma. You might also read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: the "naturally feel the need to pause" approach doesn't work for me though. somehow i find pauses natural at way more places than most people :v